# How to use concat in web2py dal select query?

Tags: sqlite, web2py

I've a table like below,

|    **id**      |  **Name**   |

| 1          | foo     |

| 2          | bar     |

I want to write a select query which should return some prep-ended text before the id. So my output should be something like, val_1 & val_2.
I couldn't see any concat method in web2py select query. To achieve my requirement I need to manipulate the result separately. Is there a way to form the select query in web2py to use SQL concat?

Comment: Hi not sure about web2py but syntax for sqlite to concat string should be like SELECT 'val_' || id AS id, name FROM table... Look [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!7/43966/3) if it's that what you mean

Comment: @AleksandarMiladinovic I want it to be done in web2py DAL. Anyway thank you for your suggestion

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `.select()` method can take SQL expressions as arguments in addition to fields, so you can do:

```
val = "'val_' || mytable.id"
rows = db(db.mytable).select(val)
print rows[0][val]
```

Note, when using an expression in the select, the resulting value is stored in the row object with a key equivalent to the SQL expression itself, hence the use of `[val]` to extract the value from the row object.

As an alternative to the above approach, you might instead consider using a [computed field](http://web2py.com/books/default/chapter/29/06/the-database-abstraction-layer#Computed-fields) or a [virtual field](http://web2py.com/books/default/chapter/29/06/the-database-abstraction-layer#Virtual-fields).

Comment: That is working perfectly. In my case, the string 'val_' will change dynamically. So I will use the first one. I hope we provide dynamic value in the virtual field when defining the table.

Comment: Is it possible to replace the value in mytable.id? Please share me if there is any document. I couldn't find anything :|

Comment: Regarding 'val_' changing dynamically, you can do that with a virtual field as well. Regarding replacing the value in the "id" field itself, no, you wouldn't do that, as the DAL requires the "id" field to be an auto-incrementing integer field.

Comment: I meant that when I retrieve the **id** I want to replace it with some other value. Let say if the id is 0 I want it to be returned as empty string.

Comment: If you can figure out the SQL to return the values you want, you can use the above method. Otherwise, you can use a computed field or virtual field, which allows you to use Python code to generate the values you want. Depending on your use case, it might also work to simply specify a "represent" attribute for the "id" field, which can be used to automatically transform the displayed values in `SQLTABLE`, `SQLFORM.grid`, and read-only forms (or in other contexts when calling the `Rows.render` method.